# QMediaPlayer, duration error

Tags: qt

When I playback files which have video frame rate of 25, the duration is shown in a correct way. But if I playback files which have a video frame rate of 29.9, the duration is wrong (less than expected).

I have the following values for the position (when values are repeated at the end, the playback is still coming) :

> 0 255 1209 2210 3208 4209 5210 6209 7210 8205 9207 10208 11211 12207
>   13209 14210 15207 16210 17209 18206 19209 20209 21207 22209 23209
>   24059 24059 24059 24059 24059 24059 24059

How can I get the correct info about duration ?

Here is the code :

```
player = new QMediaPlayer(this); 
connect(player, SIGNAL(durationChanged(qint64)), SLOT(durationChanged(qint64))); 
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), SLOT(positionChanged(qint64))); 

void durationChanged(qint64 duration) 
{ 
    this->duration = duration/1000; 
    ui->slider->setMaximum(duration / 1000); 
} 

void positionChanged(qint64 progress) 
{ 
    qDebug() << progress; 
    ui->slider->setValue(progress / 1000); 
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question in its current state. What do you mean "the duration is wrong" ? Does the video file is played entirely, or does it stop suddenly? And show some code also, a minimal working example doesn't seem to hard to achieve for this question

Comment: Video playing without problem. I mean wrong, that in fact the counter stop working, but there is a playing some several seconds

`
player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
 connect(player, SIGNAL(durationChanged(qint64)), SLOT(durationChanged(qint64)));
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)));

void durationChanged(qint64 duration) {
    this->duration = duration/1000;
    ui->slider->setMaximum(duration / 1000);
}

void positionChanged(qint64 progress) {
 qDebug() << progress;
        ui->slider->setValue(progress / 1000);
}`